# What products support 3-digit region subtags, e.g., es-419 for Latin-American Spanish?

Tags: localization, internationalization, translation

What products support 3-digit region subtags, e.g., es-419 for Latin-American Spanish?

Are web browsers, translation tools and translators familiar with these numeric codes in addition to the more common "es" or "es-ES"?

I've already visited the following pages:

- W3C [Choosing a Language Tag](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-language-tags)
- W3C [Language tags in HTML and XML](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/Overview.en.php)
- RFC 5646 [Tags for Identifying Languages](http://www.inter-locale.com/ID/rfc5646.html)
- Microsoft [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx)

Comment: I didn't see anything like this. Where did it came from?

Comment: They are defined in the region subtag, see http://www.inter-locale.com/ID/rfc5646.html#region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that many products like that exist. It seems that some main stream programming languages (I have tested C# and Java) does not support these tags, therefore it would be quite hard to develop programs that does so.

BTW. NLS API Reference that you have provided, does not contain region tag for any of the LCID definition. And if you think of it for the moment, knowing how Locale Identifier is built, there is no way to support it now, actually. Implementation change would be required (they should use some reserved bits, I suppose).

I don't think we will see support for region tags in foreseeable future.

---

**Edit**

I saw that Microsoft assigned LCID of value -1 and -2 to "European Union 1" and "European Union 2" respectively. However I don't think it is related.

Comment: Newer versions of Windows .NET allow for adding custom cultures. They all share the same LCID. Ref: "How to: Create Custom Cultures" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx

Comment: Given the lack of response to this question, I believe you are correct in suspecting most products don't support 3-digit region subtags. My primary concern is with natural language translation tools. Thanks for your reply.